# Can not open Android Studio 4 on Windows 10 - white screens instead of projects

Tags: android-studio

When I open projects in Android Studio 4.0.1 - not a single windows is opened and in preview are white screens. Sometimes deleting .idea folder helps but now I am stuck and nothing works. Do you have any idea how to solve this?
Thank you all

[Screen preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AvOPl.jpg)

Comment: I have the same problem after updating. Did you manage resolve it by reinstalling?

Comment: The problem still occurs even today.
I've reported this to google and it is in progress for a few months.
I've managed to live with that by opening random project and everytime at least one works and from this functional window I "Open new project at this window" and that seems to be working.
It's not perfect but it works for now.

Comment: Several new Android studio versions released and this bug is still not fixed. Just FYI

Answer (score 0):

This has happened to me before, to fix it I opened Android Studio -> clicked File -> clicked Invalidate Caches / Restart -> Invalidate and Restart.

If not maybe try uninstalling Android Studio, restarting you're computer and installing it again or using a program such as CCleaner to try and clean up any files which could be causing it.